# LibreOffice Calc STDEV and arrays

Tags: libreoffice-calc, worksheet-function

was reviewing an "[excel challenge](http://cl.ly/1g1N0a2b0b0P0M182d07)" and found an question that I can obtain an answer with excel 2003+ but not in LibreOffice Calc 3.5.4.2. I'm interested in why the solution doesn't work in Calc but does in Excel. For question 6:

```
{=STDEV(Range1/MID(Range2,10,4))}
```

And yes, I understand that it is a CSE formula and entered in the formula with ctrl+shift+enter in both excel and calc. Excel returns a result, Calc returns #DIV/0!.

Saving / reloading the file in xls or ODS has no effect in Calc - and Calc is configured for cells to auto calculate (Tools > Cell Contents > AutoCalculate on) so that isn't the culprit.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Difference is that with LibreOffice, MID(Range2,10,4) returns "text" elements, whereas in Excel the same formula returned as numeric elements.

```
{=STDEV(Range1/VALUE(MID(Range2,10,4)))}
```

forces LibreOffic (and Excel) to interpret elements as numeric - and returns the solution.